# Trying to pass URL from iFrame to SharePoint site URL?

Tags: facebook, sharepoint, url, iframe

I have an application running in an iFrame that is embedded in a SharePoint site. The problem with this is navigation within the application does not result in a change in the SharePoint site URL. Therefore, if you were to refresh the overall page, you would be sent back to the default page of the application, not stay on the same page of the application. The reason this is an issue is sharing for social media. I have added a Facebook Share button to the application, but when it pulls the URL of the application which does not match or reference the URL of the overall site, so it just shares the application (which is not visually appealing and does not allow you to access the rest of the site).

Any body have any suggestions or know a place I can go for help? Thanks!

Comment: Think you could provide a screenshot or similar?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly, the Facebook stuff is INSIDE the iframe?

If so, you can:
* Remove the iframe and integrate the application better with SharePoint, or
* Change the application so that it detects that it's running "alone" (with javascript etc), and if so redirect to the "big" application.

IF the Facebook stuff is in SharePoint, OUTSIDE of the iframe, you can write some javascript to update the URL in some way that matches the URL of the application. This requires that the SharePoint parent application and the iframe application run in the same domain - if they are not, this is not an option.

Note that changing the "parent" URL with JS will reload the page, UNLESS you only change the URL after the "#" part (so you can do something like:
"http://sharepoint/iframe.aspx?aa=11&bb=22#iframeUrl=http://uglyapplication/"

You'll also probably want to write JS to update your iframe accordingly if the user press "back"/"forward" etc in the browser, because changing the URL like above will still add a "step" to the browser history.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm not sure i'll be able to use any of your ideas but I will pass them along to someone else to see if we are able to do any of these things.

Comment: And yes, the Facebook stuff is inside the iFrame. And the iFrame cannot be integrated in a different way...